# html img not showing probably due to incorrect path

Tags: html, image, relative-path

I have a simple testing html page for showing a picture from my PC, it should have the correct path, yet it doesnt show the picture. I've tried every possible combination of paths I could think of, but nothing seems to make it work.

Do I even have incorrect path? Or is it because of something else? I am really lost.

[This is the project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP5u4.png)

This is the tag with the path.

```
<img src="/uploads/house.jpg" style="width: 400px;" alt="glitch">
```

[And I keep getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvBdc.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML instead of a screenshot of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ("DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc."). Are you viewing your webpage via a virtual server at an HTTP endpoint (https://localhost/) or directly via the file (file://C:users:...)? If the latter, then relative paths like this won't work how you'd expect because there's no "server root" that `/uploads/` exists in.

Comment: ok, so I edited it and I am viewing my webpage via localhost in the browser, not via the file.

Comment: Can you access the file via `http://localhost/uploads/house.jpg`?

Comment: no, I cannot access it

Comment: Well there's the problem :) you'll need to debug that further to determine why that's not accessible. Once that is resolved, your `img` tag should work as expected.

Comment: good and any advice on where to start? i'm kinda lost. I have no idea what to do or even what to ask google for any help.

Comment: maybe you can tell me wheter the relative path is correct or how the correct one should look like. I am not realy sure and nothing seems to work, also I'd like to point out that even the absolute path with "file://C:users..." doesnt work

Comment: Do you know the path of your site root? Is it `/application/app/`? If so, it looks like `uploads/` is above your site root, so you won't be able to view it via HTTP at a URL. Try moving that directory inside of `app/`, or figuring out where your site root is defined and making sure your `uploads/` is inside of that. And when you say "the absolute path doesn't work" do you mean when trying that path in an `img` tag, or when trying to view that image directly in the browser at that path?

Comment: absolute path doesnt work in the img tag, yes

Comment: Ok thank you for the help, I finally was able to make it work. The problem was with the "UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST" variable in the config file I had it equal to 'uploads' and when I changed it to '/uploads', it works fine.